# Ratchet , get client's topics on connection close

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I am using ratchet to enable push notifications for a group chat.

I have decided to do the following:

- whenever a user connects,subscribe him to all the group topics that he part of along with a personal message topic.

I have an array     `protected $subscribedTopics = array();` of topics as mentioned in ratchet's tutorial.

This will work, but over time , the number of group topics/user topics will only increase (there is no way to remove those topics from subscribed topics array).

By design, my app won't allow to send message from client to server, nor will it allow user to unsubscribe. It can only close the connection

So, I need a way to get all the topics that the user has subscribed to , when he closes(my logic is, if he is the only subscriber to some topics, remove those topics from the array of subscribed topics )

the onClose method is:

```
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    echo "close";
}
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to call unsubscribe from a topic once a connection is closed to entirely remove it from the websocket.

```
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    foreach ($conn->Chat->rooms as $topic => $one) {
        $this->onUnSubscribe($conn, $topic);
    }
}
```

Using this code you are able to unsubscribe from a $`topic` when the connection is closed.

and to make the unsubscribe working you will need something alike this:

```
function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    unset($conn->rooms['topic']);
    $this->rooms[$topic]->detach($conn);
    if ($this->rooms[$topic]->count() == 0) {
        unset($this->rooms[$topic], $this->roomLookup[array_search($topic, $this->roomLookup)]);
        $this->broadcast(static::CTRL_ROOMS, array($topic, 0));
    } else {
        $this->broadcast($topic, array('leftRoom', $conn->WAMP->sessionId));
    }
}
```

This is just an applied sample to extend the tutorial, so that it can be used by others as well.

If you need any further help please let me know

Comment: I have added you to a room Ratchet php library . Could you please talk there ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is $conn->Chat ?,and isControl() ?

Comment: it was just to remove the topic from a connection, the chat object was just for myself and can be negated

Comment: I changed the code, that should make it more clear, once you get what it does, I would suggest you to rethink it for your own application

Comment: if I am calling onUnsubscribe , how can I distinguish the request from client or the function onClose()? 
I don't want him to be able to unsubscribe

Comment: do you not want to allow unSubscribing for some users? some channels? everyone?

Comment: then you should not place any code in the unSubscribe and that will make it impossible to unsubscribe

Comment: pls see the chat again
chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/113247/ratchet-php-library

Comment: how can I connect to server in iOS ? I can't seem to find any library that works with wamp v1

Comment: its not available for iOS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113276/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-mitchken).

Comment: Can't I'm waking up

Comment: sure. Whenever you get time.